# cmake error string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments

Tags: cmake

I have got the error:

```
CMake error at CMake/winresource.cmake:7 
string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMake/winresouce.cmake:33 (_add_win_resource)
project/src/libs/ch/CMakeLists.txt:243 (add_win_resource)

CMake/winresource.cmake:7 

    string(REPLACE "." "," WIN_RESOURCE_FILEVERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

CMake/winresouce.cmake:33 (_add_win_resource)

    _add_win_resource(${TARGET} "resource.rc.in" "") 

project/src/libs/ch/CMakeLists.txt:243 (add_win_resource)

    add_version_header(${TARGET}) add_win_resource(${TARGET})
```

Comment: I seems that `PROJECT_VERSION` variable, dereferenced as the 4th parameter for `string(REPLACE)`, is either not defined or empty.

Comment: @Tsyvarev how to know it?

Comment: You could add `message` calls into appropriate places for output values of variables.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I try message(${PROJECT_VERSION}} and cmake answer: message called with incorrect number of arguments

Comment: So, it again tells that `PROJECT_VERSION` is empty. Try `message("${PROJECT_VERSION}")`.